# Getting emails with specyfic text in them scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

i'm creating a script that lists all bussiness from one website,
it need's to scrape (Name,address,website,email,telephone number).
And i got to part that i kinda can scrape email, but i have small problem, i can't just tell my script to take all of them, they are specyifc and need to contain[Biuro or Sekretariat or name part of website www.(namePart).com] and i kinda don't know how to do it.
Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import Request, Spider


class RynekMainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "RynekMain"
    start_urls = [
        'https://rynekpierwotny.pl/deweloperzy/?page=1']
    def parse(self, response):
        websites = response.css('div#root')[0]
        PAGETEST = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"rp-173nt6g")]/../following-sibling::li').css('a::attr(href)').get()
        for website in websites.css('li.rp-np9kb1'):
            page = website.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            address = website.css('address.rp-o9b83y::text').get()
            name = website.css('h2.rp-69f2r4::text').get()
            params = {
            'address' : address,
            'name' : name,
            'href' : page,
            }
            url  = response.urljoin(page)
            
            yield Request(url=url, cb_kwargs={'params': params}, callback=self.parseMain)
            
        yield Request(url=response.urljoin(PAGETEST), callback=self.parse)

    def parseMain(self, response, params=None):
        # print(response.url)
        website = response.css('div.rp-l0pkv6 a::attr(href)').get()
        params['website'] = website
        urlem = response.urljoin(website)
        yield Request(url=urlem, cb_kwargs={'params': params}, callback=self.parseEmail)
        
    
    
    
    
    def parseEmail(self,response, params=None):
        email = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "@")]/@href').get()
        params['email'] = email        
        yield params
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process =CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(RynekMainSpider)
    process.start()
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: You can do regex that complicated? And somehow including changing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `parseEmail` method, after extracting the email address, just check the extracted string like you would with any string.

For Example

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

def parseEmail(self,response, params=None):
    email = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "@")]/@href').get()
    netloc = urlsplit(response.url).netloc
    if 'Biuro' in email or 'Sekretariat' in email:
        params['email'] = email
    elif any([(i in email) for i in netloc.split('.')[:-1] if i != 'www']):
        params['email'] = email
    yield params
```